# Python: All elements of a structure change when one does

Tags: python, arrays, list, mutability

I don't understand why the following happens. Python 2.7.2

```
parinfo = [{'limited':[0,0], 'limits':[0.,0.]}] * 3 
parinfo[2]['limited'][0] = 1
parinfo[2]['limited'][0] = 1

parinfo 
[{'limited': [1, 0], 'limits': [0.0, 0.0]},
{'limited': [1, 0], 'limits': [0.0, 0.0]},
{'limited': [1, 0], 'limits': [0.0, 0.0]}]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
parinfo = [{'limited':[0,0], 'limits':[0.,0.]}] * 3
```

Above line, instead of making 3 different dictionary objects, it creates one; all items in the list reference the same dictionary.

You need to do this way to create 3 separated dictionaries:

```
parinfo = [{'limited':[0,0], 'limits':[0.,0.]} for i in range(3)]
```

Comment: @StevenRumbalski, Thank you for the comment. I updated accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Your question can be broken down into a few parts.

**First, you are multiplying a list, which leverages the __mul__() magic method.**

**s.__mul__(n)** -> results in s * n--repeated concatenation.

```
 >>> a = [1,2,3]
 >>> a * 3
 [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Furthermore, trying to initialize a list of lists will result in a list referencing three inner list, which is probably not what you want.

```
>>> a = [[]]
>>> a * 3
[[], [], []]
```

**Second, you have created a key-value pair where the value is a list.**

"limited" is the key to a list with three elements [1,2,3]

```
>>> dicty = {'limited': [1, 2, 3]}
>>> dicty['limited']
[1, 2, 3]
```

**Third, you are essentially updating the 0th element in the list.**

```
>>> dicty['l'][0] = 100
>>> dicty
{'l': [100, 2, 3]}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
parinfo = [{'limited':[0,0], 'limits':[0.,0.]}] * 3
```

This code creates a shallow copy instead of deep copy.

Comment: No not even a shallow copy. Just 3 references to the same dictionary object. See this [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) for an explanation about shallow copies (and deep copies as well).